# 64-bit floating point date and time Value to DateTime C#

Tags: c#, c++, datetime

I have got a 64-bit floating point value that I need to convert to DateTime. What I have got is a C/Cpp block of code that does that but I can not understand it, so that I can do the same in C#, help should be appreciated.

I do have this piece of information:

> Date and time of day is an eight byte, 64-bit floating-point value,
>   representing the number of days since 1 January 1900. The time of day
>   is represented as a fraction of a day.

This is the C code:

```
//Time is first 8 bytes, converted to an 8-byte float, in units of days
m1 = (unsigned int)(((((((((unsigned int)line[1]) & 0xFF)<<8) | ((unsigned int)line[2])&0xFF) << 8) | ((unsigned int)line[3])&0xFF) << 8) | ((unsigned int)line[4])&0xFF);
m2 = (unsigned int)(((((((((unsigned int)line[5]) & 0xFF)<<8) | ((unsigned int)line[6])&0xFF) << 8) | ((unsigned int)line[7])&0xFF) << 8) | ((unsigned int)line[8])&0xFF);
//Mask off mantissa bits and add back in the "hidden bit"
time = (double)((m1 & 0x000FFFFF) | 0x00100000) + ((double)m2)/thirty_two_bits;
time = time / 32.0; //Normalise by "shifting right" to complete mantissa extraction
exp = (m1 >> 20) - 0x0400 - 14; //The above calculation is good for an exponent of 14...
while (exp != 0){
if (exp < 0){
    time = time / 2.0;
    exp++;
}else{
    time = time * 2.0;
exp--;
}
}
time = time * 3600.0 * 24.0;    //Convert days to seconds
```

Where `line` is a byte array containing the 8-bytes for the date and time starting at index [1].

A sample value for `line` is: `{X, 64, 228, 8, 46, 222, 232, 221, 125, ...}`.

I did try the following but no correct results: (C#):

```
long longvalue = BitConverter.ToInt64(line, 1);
DateTime dtm = DateTime.FromBinary(longvalue);
```

Comment: The above code is C, I need to do the process in C# (I'd tried code conversion from C to C# but it results to time equals extremely small values e.g.: "1.1147586588607491E-308" or "Infinity", due to the while loop!)

Comment: Use a MemoryStream to store the bytes, BinaryReader.GetBytes() to read 8 bytes from it, Array.Reverse() to reverse the bytes, BitConverter.ToDouble() to convert the byte[] to a double, DateTime.FromOADate() to convert to a date.  Your sample bytes produce {4/26/2012 11:09:11 AM}, looks like a happy date.

Comment: Hans Passant, thank you, perfect, but my question now is: Why do I need to reverse the bytes order, is that related by any means to BitConverter.IsLittleEndian?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered by Hans Passant in his commment on the question:

> Use a MemoryStream to store the bytes, `BinaryReader.GetBytes()` to
>   read 8 bytes from it, `Array.Reverse()` to reverse the bytes,
>   `BitConverter.ToDouble()` to convert the `byte[]` to a `double`,
>   `DateTime.FromOADate()` to convert to a date. Your sample bytes
>   produce {4/26/2012 11:09:11 AM}, looks like a happy date.

Thanks Hans Passant.